# angularjs - directive not working for a dynamically added class

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Me1S6MV9XKOPIc6EJq8?p=preview) - I have button that toggles the class `toggled` on the body element.

And I've created a directive to open a alert when the `toggled` class is assigned to the body element currently which is not working.

But the alert do work if I remove the `toggled` class on the body element.

Can I any please let me know why this is happening?

And why it's working when I create a directive that is referenced to the a element where the class is added dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To avoid this question being closed as "link-only" I suggest you put _relevant_ part of the code in the question. (Try reading the question assuming that the link to plunker is broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, to register click handler dynamically you must use different syntax of `jQuery.on`:

Instead of this

```
  $('toggled > .alert').click(function() {
    alert("Yes!");
  })
```

Use this

```
  $(document).on('click', 'toggled > .alert', function() {
    alert("Yes!");
  })
```

Also, if you want to show separate dialog for element, where your directive registered, you must to register click handler on element itself and check is it complies to selector:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  element.on('click', function() {
    if (jQuery(this).is('.toggled > .alert')) {
      alert("Yes!");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the directive, all you need to do to trigger the alert is;

```
app.directive('openAlert', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $(element).click(function() {
        if ($(element).parent().hasClass('toggled')) alert("Yes!");
      })
    }
  }

})
```

Here's the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/IuL5Z4yQgIfVy6AtId4L?p=preview

Comment: It works all the times. I wanted it to work only when the body has the class `toggled`.

Comment: Have you checked the plunk?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this without using jQuery. Check out the solution below.

1. No need to set the `toggle` on the `ng-init` directive, set it in the Controller.
2. Use `ng-click` directive on the anchor tag
3. Declare an `alert` function in the Directive and invoke it on `ng-click`, this eliminating the need for jQUery
4. In the `alert` function check if the `scope.toggle` is `true` or `false` before you trigger the alert.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-class="{toggled: toggle}">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle Class</button>
    <a href="#" ng-click="alert()" open-alert>Open the alert box!</a>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
});

app.directive('openAlert', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.alert = function () {
                if (!!scope.toggle) {
                    alert('Yes!');
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/4zshgwt7/)**